# Ubuntu 10.04 Update Manager freezes

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

So I have a lot of VM's with ubuntu 10.04 which recently went off of support.

I don't really care that it went off of support but the window that Ubuntu is showing to tell me this fact is freezing up, and it keeps launching more and more copies of Update manager to tell me this fact.

Including a screenshot of the message.  When I click close it just freezes and I have to manually kill the process, but then it comes back later.  Any suggestion on how I remove the warning?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I should have googled better.

The solution to this is from https://askubuntu.com/questions/122165/10-10-irritating-updater-message

> Just open software sources and set Release Upgrade to Never under the Updates tab.This stops the message from recurring. Thats it.